# Counting in binary by lowest number of 1s to largest number of 1s (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to count from 0 to *n*, and represent the value in binary.  Using Java, this is easy using Integer.toBinaryString().  However, I would like to produce the output in the order of a number of 1's.  For example, counting 0 to 7:

```
[000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 101, 110, 111]
```

Ordering within a "class" (one 1, two 1's, etc) is somewhat irrelevant in the context of the problem I'm solving.  So 011, 101, 110 could be 110, 011, 101.

Instead of the following, which is a result of counting 0 to 7, and getting the binary string:

```
[000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111]
```

I can't seem to wrap my brain around how to approach this.

Comment: Sorry. But you did only drop (home) work assignments. Include what you tried so far!

Comment: @GhostCat What makes you think this is a homework question? Only debugging questions are required to include code. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224104/244864 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/244864 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259947/2891664 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259950/2891664

Comment: @Radiodef What makes you think it is something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your searching for is `Integer.bitCount(i)` (available since Java 1.5) which returns the number of one-bits.

With Java 8 you can store your numbers into an array and sort it by `bitCount` ascending:

```
    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) numbers[i] = i;
    Arrays.sort(numbers, Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::bitCount));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Or if you want to use the Java 8 Streams:

```
    List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.range(0, 8)
            .boxed()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::bitCount))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(numbers);
```

---

If you cannot use Java 8 the `Comparator` is slightly more involved:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) numbers[i] = i;
    Arrays.sort(numbers, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return Integer.bitCount(o1)-Integer.bitCount(o2);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Comment: @Radiodef we can instead use [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)  also I think we can generate those numbers in a more efficient way

Comment: Nice. He dropped his homemade and you dropped all the code.

Comment: Had no idea about bitCount().  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to order the output, it seems like that means you want to sort it. This could be done many ways, but it would ultimately come down to writing a `Comparator`.

Here's an example using [`bitCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> set =
            new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::bitCount)
                                    .thenComparing(naturalOrder()));
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 7)
                 .forEach(set::add);
        String s = set.stream()
                      .map(Integer::toBinaryString)
                      .collect(joining(", ", "[", "]"));
        // [0, 1, 10, 100, 11, 101, 110, 111]
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```